# Positive lookbehind vs non-capturing group: different behaviuor

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind, capturing-group

I use python regular expressions (`re` module) in my code and noticed different behaviour in theese cases:

```
re.findall(r'\s*(?:[a-z]\))?[^.)]+', 'a) xyz. b) abc.') # non-capturing group
# results in ['a) xyz', ' b) abc']
```

and

```
re.findall(r'\s*(?<=[a-z]\))?[^.)]+', 'a) xyz. b) abc.') # lookbehind
# results in ['a', ' xyz', ' b', ' abc']
```

What I need to get is just `['xyz', 'abc']`. Why are the examples behave differently and how t get the desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason `a` and `b` are included in the **second case** is because `(?<=[a-z]\))`  would first find `a)` and since lookaround's don't consume any character you are **back** at the start of string.Now `[^.)]+` matches `a`

Now you are at `)`.Since you have made `(?<=[a-z]\))` optional `[^.)]+` matches `xyz`

This same thing is repeated with `b) abc`

remove `?` from the second case and you would get the expected result i.e `['xyz', 'abc']`

Comment: The non-capturing group in the first case is optional, too (if no `a)` in text, then match the whole text).

Comment: @chersanya that's why i had said second case not first case..there is difference between them

Comment: @chersanya also lookarounds checks for the specified pattern but it doesn't eat any characters..hence the result

Comment: Oh, I've got it) The real issue is that lookarounds don't consume anything, so findall finds `a` in `a)` too.

Comment: Would you add the reason to your answer?

Comment: @chersanya: The "not consume anything" is not a good explanation. The text which are skipped can be considered consumed. The reason your original regex fail is plainly because of the `?`.

Comment: @nhahtdh: are you sure? Lookbehind doesn't consume text, so occurences of `a` in `a)` and `abc` in `abc` are non-overlapping. If it consumed, there would be no difference with the first case I provided.

Comment: @chersanya: Look-behind doesn't consume text is correct. But since you make the look-behind optional, the regex is effectively `\s*[^.)]+`. Making look-behind optional seems to be only supported in Python and I don't know why they allow it - it doesn't make sense to do such thing, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh: but if it consumed the text, the regex with lookbehind would  (my 2nd case) be equivalent to the first case, which obviously differs from `\s*[^.)]+`? Or no (why)?

Comment: @nhahtdh lookarounds can be optional..it's allowed in `.net`..but i agree that it really doesn't make sense

Comment: @chersanya: What I meant is that, due to `?`, the regex is **made equivalent** to `\s*[^.)]+`, since the result of the look-behind (whether true or false) doesn't stop the match.

Comment: @chersanya: The "not consume anything" argument may come to play in some other case, but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are looking for is:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=[a-z]\) )[^) .]+', 'a) xyz. b) abc.')
```

I believe the currently accepted answer by Anirudha explains the differences between your use of positive lookbehind and non-capturing well, however, the suggestion of removing the `?` from after the positive lookbehind actually results in `[' xyz', ' abc']` (note the included spaces).

This is due to the positive lookbehind not matching the `space` character as well as not including `space` in the main matching character class itself.